# How to write a transaction using jdbc driver?

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, transactions

I want to write a transaction using jdbc in `java`.

I have tried this simple transaction

```
"BEGIN TRANSACTION"+NL+"GO"+NL+"UPDATE table SET col='test' where id=1010"+NL+"GO"+NL+"COMMIT"
```

I have tried with

```
NL= "\n" and NL="\r\n" and NL="\r"
```

but I get always the following error:

> java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.

In `sql server management studio` the transaction works

Comment: Does it help sending separate commands without embedded newlines?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Get your Connection object. Turn off auto commit.

```
connection.setAutoCommit(false);
```

Wrap your entire transaction in a `try`-`catch` block. When you finish processing your inserts/updates, call:

```
connection.commit();
```

If you get an exception, call:

```
connection.rollback();
```

Don't put the transaction statements in your JDBC's SQL at that point. I suggest looking at wrappers, such as Hibernate and JPA. Transactions in JDBC can get pretty long winded.